# How do I do analysis of mysites in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, mysites, analytics

I have a seperate web app running my sites, I want to run some analysis to find out how many mysites are there, how many of them are actively used, which one's have the highest number of viewers and which one's were never used and when was each one of them last used. The mysites at the moment are still running in 2010 mode and they need to uplifted but before that I needed these measure.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the stats can be gathered from PowerShell others you may want to look at usage analytics or 3rd party tools.

They can stay in 2010 mode. Analytics in 2013 is handled by the Search Service Application and the Usage and Health Data Collection Service Application, so you need that before your analytics will work. Then configure Usage and Health Data Collection (under Monitoring in Central Administration).

The info is all dumped into a logging database that you write your reports against. (WSS_Logging by default, but you may change that.)